# Android Studio 2.3.3 -- Horizontal progress bar

Tags: android, android-studio, progress-bar, android-progressbar, android-studio-2.3

How to create a horizontal progress bar in android studio 2.3.3 and in a browser app? i have created a progress bar in XML and initialized it in Main Activity 
**activity_main:**

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="3dp"
        android:layout_y="5dp" />
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
ProgressBar pb;
pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
```

Should I use WebChrome Client ? please help.

Comment: Use `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Images");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.show();
```